# function definition with arguments

Tags: coffeescript

I am newbie of CoffeeScript so maybe my question is not constructive. If so, I am sorry. Anyway, the problem is writing function. I tried 2 ways as below but variables didn't work well. How should I write this?

1st way: arg.foo

```
triangle = (arg...) ->
    if arg.base == undefined then arg.base = 1;
    if arg.height == undefined then arg.height = 1;
    arg.base * arg.height / 2

document.writeln triangle
    base:8
    height:5 # => return 0.5 ...
```

2nd way: arg['foo']

```
triangle = (arg...) ->
    if arg['base'] == undefined then arg['base'] = 1;
    if arg['height'] == undefined then arg['height'] = 1;
    arg['base'] * arg['height'] / 2

document.writeln triangle
    base:8
    height:5 # => return 0.5 ...
```

Thank you for your kindness.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm taking this opportunity to mention a few other niceties:

Your first attempt with `arg...` doesn't work, since the `...` syntax (called a [*splat*](http://coffeescript.org/#splats)) will take the remaining arguments and put them in the array `arg`.

An improvement to your default parameters is:

```
triangle = (arg) ->
    arg.base ?= 1
    arg.height ?= 1

    arg.base * arg.height / 2
```

The construct `?=` is using the [existential operator](http://coffeescript.org/#operators), and `arg.base ?= 1` will assign `1` to `arg.base` iff `arg.base` is `null` or `undefined`.

But it gets even better! Coffeescript has support for [destructuring assignment](http://coffeescript.org/#destructuring), so you can write:

```
triangle = ({base, height}) ->
    base ?= 1
    height ?= 1

    base * height / 2
```

If you prefer, you could use Coffeescript's default arguments like this:

```
triangle = ({base, height} = {base: 1, height: 2}) ->
    base * height / 2
```

But that would *not* work if you want to be able to specify *only* `base` or `height`, i.e. if you call it like `triangle(base: 3)`, `height` will be `undefined`, so probably not what you want.

Answer (score 0):

I am sorry that I found the answer. I should use `arg` instead of `arg...`.

```
triangle = (arg) ->
    if arg.base == undefined then arg.base = 1;
    if arg.height == undefined then arg.height = 1;
    arg.base * arg.height / 2

document.writeln triangle
    base:8
    height:5 # => return 20 !!!
```